# No files showing in a Visual Studio 2015 Blank Cordova project

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I'm struggling with ionic and cordova since few days now, one of the last issue I had is when I create a sample blank project in visual studio, the solution explorer is showing no files except the dependencies to Bower and NPM, do you know why?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

To fix this problem, please close Visual Studio and do the following steps:

1. Open a Visual Studio Developer command prompt.
2. Run devenv /clearcache

Or, delete this folder:

%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

When you restart Visual Studio the problem should go away.

Comment: Hi Michael, after trying both ways I still have the issue. I've tried different version of Node, Cordova, Ionic and NPM but still the same. I tried as well to repair my VS installation without success even by overriding my current environment variables.

Comment: I work on the tools for apache Cordova in Visual Studio. I'd like to have one of our engineers look into this problem. Could you please contact us at vscordovatools@microsoft.com so we can arrange a time to debug your machine?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've contacted you via email. To give you the error I get when forcing the inclusion of the www folder for example, I get this error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1oQzo.png

Answer (score 0):

try the following to find out...

Open cmd and type:

```
1. cd [project folder]
2. cordova build
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe, I got some errors mentionning I don't have the right SDK althought I have installed correctly android SDK. Why should I install Windows SDK like mentionned below?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1966,5): warning MSB3785: No SDKs were found. SDKReference items will not b
e resolved. If your application requires these references there may be compilation errors. [D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp4\Blank
CordovaApp4\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(705,5): error APPX3213: SDK folder containing 'Windows.props' for 'Windows 8.1' cannot be located.

Comment: Well, I've installed the WIndows SDK and was able to compile but I'm still ending up with the empty project issue..