# VS2015 Ionic 2 Error on debug: could not locate the start page

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ionic2

When I build and debug Ionic 2 project in Visual Studio 2015, show this error

Error DEP10402: Could not locate the start page. You may need to build your project.

I use this versions:
node: 4.1.2
Cordova: 6.5.0
Ionic: 2.2.1
Visual Studio: 2015 update 3

Answer (score 0):

in package.json ;

"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },

solved problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. Ionic template is based on earlier version, you are using latest version, so there are some issues because of it. And VS has nodejs in web\external tools dir, which is older version than the one you would see on nodejs.org.

Solution:

- fix the versions for your dependencies in package.json, and make sure you are using app-scripts 1.0.0 in your devDependencies
- instead of using node/npm from *VSINSTALLDIR/web/external* I'm using global installation of node and npm, to do that go to external tools configuration in VS, and remove the entries from there, just keep *$PATH*, I assume you have global installation of GIT, so you can remove it too.

**OR**

You can create project using the ionic cli

```
ionic start MyIonic2Project --v2
```

then import it in visual studio, it should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When updating app scripts to 1.0.0 make sure NPM is finished before starting your app.