# Cordova Android Debug Error DEP10402 Could not locate the start page

Tags: android, cordova

I'm having a very big trouble, cause I can't start debug Andoid in browser.

- I can build apk
- I can build ipa
- I can start debug iOS in brobser

**Android Platform 7.1.0**

Only android debug is an issue and it's a big issue, cause I can't test my app as Android.

I saw this post but non of answers are helpful.

[Error DEP10402: Could not locate the start page. You may need to build your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631133/error-dep10402-could-not-locate-the-start-page-you-may-need-to-build-your-proj)

Any ideas about which way to research?